# Long pause after login using display manager

Tags: xorg, gdm

I have a strange problem with Ubuntu, that I never had before:

when using GDM3 (or any other display manager I've tested) and Xorg,
after logging in I have to wait for 5 or more minutes, until my session
starts. After that it works just fine.

When using Wayland it works without any problems.
When using `startx`/`xinit` it works like a charm too.

This problem is definitely quite common, but I didn't manage
to find a solution, though there are a lot of reports with similar symptoms.

My system is fresh (just installed) `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`.

What could I check? What could I fix?

Comment: How about your logs? What do they show?

Comment: @user535733: Which logs should I check?

Comment: If you don't know, then check ALL your logs. You can likely exclude logs with last-modified timestamps before the problem appeared. Logs are a very common troubleshooting tool. If you did enough research to determine that "*there are a lot of reports with similar symptoms*" but none of those many reports mention logs, then that research --and that conclusion-- may be suspect.